# Android draw a part of scaled bitmap using canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm using canvas and have an image 1000x500, phone width 480 and height 800

Scale sample:

```
        scale = (float) (height / image.getHeight());
        image_width = image.getWidth() * scale;
        image_height = image.getHeight() * scale;
```

How do I draw this scaled image using canvas, having only center(screen size) of the image visible while left and right sides are outside of screen?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) - you probably don’t want to waste memory and it might help answering your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it this way

```
Rect rs = new Rect();
Rect rd = new Rect();
rs.left = rs.top = 0;
rs.right = 480;
rs.bottom = 800;

<calculate destination rectangle from device size>

canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, rs, rd, null);
```

You can also scale and translate (shift) the entire canvas

```
canvas.scale(float scaleX, float scaleY);
canvas.translate(float dx, float dy);
```

Comment: This will work, but I agree with @Droid that the bitmap in memory should not be larger than the target rendering size.

Comment: canvas.scale(float scaleX, float scaleY); worked fine, thank you )

Comment: I've added canvas.scale(x, y) and now it works very slow. If I draw only one bitmap, it works fine, but if I add more, then it is like a slide show. How it can be fixed?